# Sqlite in C programming

Tags: c, sqlite, server, client, status

I am trying to implement a server-client communication. I am executing a sql statement (**SQLITE3**)

```
"UPDATE users SET status=1 WHERE username='%s' AND password='%s';",user,pass);
```

using `qlite3_prepare_v2`

I know how to write to client, but I don't know how to CHECK if the 'status' has been set to 1 where username is user and password is pass AND how to send a reply to client: "Yes, the 'status' has been set to 1, you are now logged in"

Comment: Is the question how to read something from database? Or how to verify a "write-only query"? The latter is discussed in the answer below, but I think you are actualyl asking about the former. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I wanted to verify if the "status" column were updated after last statement(if the user is logged in or not).

Comment: Please [edit] to improve the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int sqlite3_changes(sqlite3*);` returns the number of rows modified, inserted or deleted by the most recently completed INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement.

After your query, check if one row was modified.

Source: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for.